# .NET CF on Windows CE - problem with filtering system messages

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, windows-messages

I'm trying to get every windows message that tells that the user has touched the screen. It works everywhere, except the button, when it is disabled. It seems that the application doesn't get any message when clicked on disabled control.

I'm using OpenNetCF Application2 class for filtering messages:

`Application2.AddMessageFilter(Device.PowerManager);

    Application2.Run(new MainForm());`

PowerManager class contains a following method (as required by IMessageFilter interface):

```
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Message m)
    {
        log.DebugFormat("windows message {0} - 0x{0:X}", m.Msg);
        if (m.Msg == 0x0201 || m.Msg == 0x8001 || m.Msg == 0x0005)
        {                
            return this.ResetPowerManager();       
        }

        return false;
    }
```

in the log file there is no indication of a windows message when clicking on disabled button.
I'm wondering how is it possible and how can I get this message.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, the Win32 API function [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa927344.aspx) could be used. You can pass the handle of your main form to it and it will capture all mouse events until you call [ReleaseCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933042.aspx).